# Where can I download a non-minified version of jQuery UI?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I'm trying to customize the [autocomplete combobox](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox)

with the intent of using it for nested lists with flyouts. Starting this with the minified version of jQuery UI is obviously not ideal. The download builder only provides minified downloads.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Look within your standard downloaded zip from [jqueryui.com/download](http://jqueryui.com/download), there is a folder:

```
development-bundle/ui
```

within that folder, you have everything you need, in non-minimized format. :) You don't need to look any further..

Answer (score 10):

**For jQuery UI:**

- You can get the *latest* source right from github [here](http://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/tree/master/ui/)
- For the full *combined* **release** of jquery-ui.js, grab it from [Google's CDN](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/jquery-ui.js)

**For jQuery Core:**

- Same goes for [jQuery core](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/tree/master/src/)
- And the [CDN/combined version](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js)

Comment: Note that if you truncate the version, you'll get the highest numbered subversion.  For example, `jquery/1/jquery.js` is equivalent to `jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js` (the current version), `jquery/1.3/jquery.js` is equivalent to `jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js`, and `jquery/1.2/jquery.js` will get you `jquery/1.2.6/jquery.js`